# How to create a screen and execute a sudo command

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sudo, gnu-screen

I need a script to create a screen session and run a command inside, then detach and proceed with other screens. So I need something like `screen -S vault -d -m $HOME/vault/v.sh`. However, `v.sh` requires sudo privileges. What are my options?

1. Leave it like that and run the whole script as `sudo`. Problem: the other scripts/sessions will also run as `sudo`, which is undesirable.
2. Insert `sudo` at the start: `sudo screen -S vault -d -m $HOME/vault/v.sh`.
3. Insert it before calling `v.sh`: `screen -S vault -d -m "sudo $HOME/vault/v.sh"`

What is the best option?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. It's someone you have to make your mind up about. it looks like you know how to solve your problem. You even list some of the pro and con arguments.

Comment: Well, I'm still a noob here, being a long time Windows user. So I definitely don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

One option you haven't listed is that if v.sh itself requires sudo privs, put that in the shebang line at the top of the script:

```
$ head -1 $HOME/vault/v.sh
#!/usr/bin/sudo /bin/sh
```

This method has the slight advantage that your master script doesn't require any knowledge of which scripts require sudo and which don't.

Comment: The problem with putting `sudo` in `v.sh` is that it requires entering the password inside the screen. SO I have to manually go to the screen and enter it, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: One way to get around that is to edit your `sudoers` file to allow your account to run the script without entering a password.  A line in your sudoers file like `ulu ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /home/ulu/vault/v.sh` might be what you need.